# htaccess non www to www not working, other redirects working

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have an issue with my non www to www redirect. Everything else in my .htaccess file works as expected. My htaccess looks as follows.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.mysite\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mysite.com/$1 [R=301,L]

# Redirect old URLs to new ones
RewriteRule ^(about)$ about-us [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^(contact-us)$ contact [L,R=301]

#Place index.php after hostname
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond $2 !\.(gif|jpe?g|png|css|pdf|swf|fla|ppt|php|js)$ [NC]
RewriteCond $1 !\.(gif|jpe?g|png|css|pdf|swf|fla|ppt|php|js)$ [NC]

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

The other redirects work , just the non www to www doesn't. Can anyone point me in the right direction. Thanks

Comment: Have you run a phpinfo script with various domain synonyms to validate that your host is setting HTTP_HOST correctly?  Some hosting services process this in the Apache root config and reset it

Comment: @TerryE Thanks for the reply, it seems to be set correctly.                                                             HTTP_HOST www.mysite.com
 HTTP_CONNECTION keep-alive

Comment: @Henrick do you happen to have multiple .htaccess files on different directories ?

Answer (score 0):

The same issue I was too struggling with. And finally I found solution for that. If you are using virtual host, then In your virtual host settings change:
`ServerAlias *.domain.com` to  `ServerAlias domain.com`

This will resolve your problem. I don't know why its causing the issue, but someone apache expert can help on this.